# In Angular, I Can't get my render paths correct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to Angular (and plan to spend the whole week on it), and I'm following a tutorial on youtube and I think the guy who created it must have took a trip to another galaxy so there's no support anymore (but an awesome tut). I can't seem to get my home..html page to render to the browser and I'm at a total lost.
When I enter this URL manually: 
https://chore-master-j-s-thomas-1.c9users.io/home
The error I get is: Cannot GET /home
So I'm thinking it has to be my routing.

this is my app.js page

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',                                            function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',       controller: 'homeController.js'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false});          }])
```

And here is my index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other     head content must come *after* these tags -->
 <meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
 <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">              <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <body>
     <div class="container">
  <div class="header clearfix">
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>   </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <h3 class="text-muted">Chore Master</h3>
  </div>
 <p class='container' style="margin-left: 50" align="left" >text</p >
 <!-- Main Container -->
  <div class="container">
  <div ng-view></div>
 </div>  

</div> <!-- /container -->

 <!-- scripts to import for angularjs goes here -->
<scripts type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.js">        </scripts>
<scripts type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-      route.js"></scripts>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/homeController.js">         </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and then my home controller:

```
  myApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  }]);
```

I'm really not sure what else will help besides my github but can anyone tell me what I have wrong and what angular parts do I need to study?

Here's my github repo:
      https://github.com/J-S-Thomas/Chore_Master.git

Answer (score 1):

You have some small typos when importing angular files:

```
<scripts type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.js"></scripts>
<scripts type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"</scripts>
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Notice the html tag is *script*, not *scripts*. And the folder where you placed them is *lib* not *libs*.

Answer (score 0):

There might be something wrong with your hosting. When I browse to https://chore-master-j-s-thomas-1.c9users.io/ your index page works ok. But when I attempt to access https://chore-master-j-s-thomas-1.c9users.io/libs/angular/angular.js I get the "cannot GET" error. Your site isn't loading any of your js libs so Angular isn't even launching.

Update: your Bootstrap css is under "lib", remove the "s" from the js libs script tags. Also note you have a typo in those tags where you also added an s.